# Run tests against compiled bundles

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

As a **JS library** author I **compile and publish** my source code in the following formats:

- commonJS (`/lib/index.js`)
- ES (`/es/index.js`)
- UMD (`/dist/index.js`)

My unit tests cover my source code and I **trust my bundling/compiling tools** to generate working bundles.

Then I read [this enlightening post](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/12/15/improving-the-repository-infrastructure.html#running-tests-on-compiled-bundles) by React team where they explain that they run **part of their unit tests against the bundled version** of the library.

They introduced a `test-build-prod` which **runs Jest** with a [special configuration file](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1209ae50f3490b76d2de777837359f8c1ad910fa/scripts/jest/config.build.js) which **replace the original import declarations** in the test to point the bundled files using Jest's [`moduleNameMapper`  option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string).

It's cool but a bit overwhelming to replicate in my tiny open source side projects.

Before I give this a try, is there **any other tool or more portable solution** I should consider to run the same test I run on my source code against the compiled bundles?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll share the solution I finally went with, which is the same adopted by React team but on small scale.

I added a special **npm script** to **run my unit tests against each compiled bundle** with a different **Jest configuration** for each bundle:

```
{
    "test:bundles": "jest --config ./jest/es.config.js && jest --config ./jest/lib.config.js && jest --config ./jest/dist.config.js"
}
```

Each Jest configuration file **extends default Jest configuration** and declares a [`moduleNameMapper`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#modulenamemapper-object-string-string) object plus a [`rootDir`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#rootdir-string) property like:

```
// jest/lib.config.js
const pkg = require('../package.json');

module.exports = Object.assign({}, pkg.jest, {
  rootDir: '../',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '/src/index$': '<rootDir>/lib/index', // path of "CommonJS" bundle
  },
});
```

`moduleNameMapper` will make sure that the **same tests used for source code** will run **against an exported bundle** since **Jest will transform the import statements** on runtime like:

```
import myLibrary from './src/index';
// transformed into:
import myLibrary from '../lib/index';
```

The only point to pay attention to is making **tests import statements needing remapping easily recognizable** by `moduleNameMapper` regex.

If `import from './index'` is not unique enough in test the files, it might be rewritten as `import from '../src/index'`.

Comment: Do you use `jest.mock(...)` in your tests? Did you have any problems with it using this approach?